# Nav menu not appearing for a single user using chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-chrome

We have recently changed our navigation menus. They have been working fine for everyone except for one user only when that user is using chrome.

The menu will render when they hover over an option the first time but after that, no menus render (see screenshots).

We are using the exact same version of chrome rendering the same website. Has anyone else ever experienced anything like this or have any ideas what could cause this?

*Working:*

[image]

*Broken:*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the issue.

Firstly, everyone was using the same version of chrome in incognito mode with no extensions and a cleared cache so we're *still* not sure why only one specific user was getting the issue and no one else. Also that user was 2000 miles away so we could not physically debug on that machine. (It was an manager/admin with sensitive info on the machine so RDP was also not an option)

I was finally able to reproduce the issue by testing using Chrome Canary and discovered that the issue was directly related to hiding the sub-fly-out menus off screen using left -999999999px instead of display: none. Apparently just holding the '9' key down for a few seconds was a bad idea and it seemed to cause an overflow error of some kind and changing the left value to -9999px instead fixed it for that user and everyone else in Chrome Canary.

Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me very much like a caching issue. Some of the JavaScript or CSS from before the update may still be stored in the user's browser cache.

To resolve this, clear Chrome's browser cache.
You can access the relevant dialog via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>.

Comment: You can also right click on the reload button in chrome with DevTools open. This will give you a few options for reloading. A little easier IMO. Still +1 though. Good call. FYI there is also a setting in DevTools - `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have tried clearing cache's in just about every possible way to no avail.

Comment: Are the browser versions the same? Are the installed/running plug-ins the same? Did you try to reinstall Chrome? Any special security settings? Any experimental features (`chrome://flags`) activated?